# Adding a wave texture to a specific part of my texture

Tags: texturing

My question is: how can i add a wave texture on a specific part of my mesh, using only nodes?

I'm trying to replicate something from an image but can't figure how to texturize it.
Here's what i'm trying to reproduce
[image]

sorry for my bad english

This is my node setup [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Musgrave as a stencil between two parts of a Color Mix Node, one taking the Waves texture and the other some other texture.[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Add a second (wave) material. Unwrap your whole mesh. In layout mode select the faces you want to be "wavey" then **assign** the second material. Hope that helps